# Docker Compose failing with file not found error pywintypes.error: (2, 'CreateFile', 'The system cannot find the file specified.') on windows

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to run below command on windows command prompt. It is failing with file not found error.

```
C:\Users\AMRANE\cp-all-in-one\cp-all-in-one>docker-compose up -d
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages\docker\api\client.py", line 205, in _retrieve_server_version
  File "site-packages\docker\api\daemon.py", line 181, in version
  File "site-packages\docker\utils\decorators.py", line 46, in inner
  File "site-packages\docker\api\client.py", line 228, in _get
  File "site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 543, in get
  File "site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 530, in request
  File "site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 643, in send
  File "site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 449, in send
  File "site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 677, in urlopen
  File "site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 392, in _make_request
  File "http\client.py", line 1244, in request
  File "http\client.py", line 1290, in _send_request
  File "http\client.py", line 1239, in endheaders
  File "http\client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
  File "http\client.py", line 966, in send
  File "site-packages\docker\transport\npipeconn.py", line 32, in connect
  File "site-packages\docker\transport\npipesocket.py", line 23, in wrapped
  File "site-packages\docker\transport\npipesocket.py", line 72, in connect
  File "site-packages\docker\transport\npipesocket.py", line 59, in connect
pywintypes.error: (2, 'CreateFile', 'The system cannot find the file specified.')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "docker-compose", line 3, in <module>
  File "compose\cli\main.py", line 67, in main
  File "compose\cli\main.py", line 123, in perform_command
  File "compose\cli\command.py", line 69, in project_from_options
  File "compose\cli\command.py", line 132, in get_project
  File "compose\cli\docker_client.py", line 43, in get_client
  File "compose\cli\docker_client.py", line 170, in docker_client
  File "site-packages\docker\api\client.py", line 188, in __init__
  File "site-packages\docker\api\client.py", line 213, in _retrieve_server_version
docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: (2, 'CreateFile', 'The system cannot find the file specified.')
```

Answer (score 7):

Starting Docker desktop should take care of this problem.

Comment: I have the same problem, having docker compose only. I have not installed docker desktop.